# Updating state of parent component when a child component is clicked, returns an error saying "cannot read property..."

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to update the parent components state when the child component has been clicked. I seem to be able to able to pass the information I need from the child component, and when I console.log the station name it works. The problem starts when I am trying to update the state. It returns an error saying that the "Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined". I am unsure why it is doing this?

**Child Component**

```
export default function StationListItem(props) {
  const boldString = (str, substr) => {
    var strRegExp = new RegExp(substr, "gi");
    var newString = str.match(strRegExp);
    var x = str.replace(newString, "<b>" + newString + "</b>");
    return x;
  };

  const { name, query, action } = props;

  return (
    <li
      onClick={() => {
        action(name);
      }}
      name={name}
      dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: boldString(name, query) }}
    ></li>
  );
}
```

**Parent Component**

```
import "../../App.sass";
import StationListItem from "../Account/StationListItem";

const searchListStyles = {
  margin: 0,
  padding: 0,
  listStyleType: "none",
  border: "1px solid #ccc",
  borderTop: "0px",
  borderRadius: "0 0 5px 5px",
  height: "100%",
  maxHeight: "228px",
  overflow: "scroll",
};

export default class SaveFavouriteStations extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      searchField_isFocused: false,
      query: "",
      stationsArr: [],
      filteredArr: [],
      selectedArr: ["Leigh-on-Sea"],
      selected: "",
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("api/stations")
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((stations) => {
        this.setState({ stationsArr: stations });
      });
  }

  handleSearch(e) {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value.toLowerCase() });

    const filtered = this.state.stationsArr.filter((station) => {
      if (
        station.station_name
          .toLowerCase()
          .includes(this.state.query.toLowerCase()) ||
        station.crs_code.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.query.toLowerCase())
      ) {
        return station;
      }
    });

    this.setState({ filteredArr: filtered });
  }

  searchFocusHandler(e) {
    console.log(e);
    this.setState({ searchField_isFocused: true });
  }

  clickHandler(name) {
    this.setState({
      selected: name,
    });
  }

  render() {
    const {
      filteredArr,
      selectedArr,
      query,
      searchField_isFocused,
    } = this.state;

    const matchingStations = filteredArr.map((station) => {
      return (
        <StationListItem
          key={station._id}
          name={station.station_name}
          query={query}
          action={this.clickHandler}
        />
      );
    });

    const selected = selectedArr.map((selected) => {
      return selected;
    });

    return (
      <div className="section favourite-stations">
        <h1>Favourite Stations</h1>
        <input
          autoComplete="off"
          className="text-input"
          type="text"
          name="query"
          placeholder="Search for a station..."
          onChange={(e) => {
            this.handleSearch(e);
          }}
          onFocus={() => {
            this.setState({ searchField_isFocused: true });
          }}
          onMouseDown={() => {
            this.setState({ searchField_isFocused: false });
          }}
        />
        {searchField_isFocused ? (
          <ul style={searchListStyles}>
            {query.length >= 2 ? (
              matchingStations
            ) : (
              <div style={{ padding: "10px 0", color: "#ccc" }}>
                Enter a station name or code
              </div>
            )}
          </ul>
        ) : (
          ""
        )}
        <div>{selectedArr.length >= 1 ? selected : "no stations selected"}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your event handlers to arrow functions, otherwise `this` is undefined:

```
handleSearch(e) {
   // this is undefined 
   this.setState(); // => "Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined"
}

handleSearch = (e) => {
   // this is defined
   this.setState(); // works :)
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked. I did think this was the problem, but didn't implement code correctly.

Answer (score 1):

you have to `bind this` for functions in constructor :

```
this.clickHandler = this.clickHandler.bind(this)
//other functions
```

Or, change declaration type :

```
clickHandler = (e) => {//your code}
//other functions
```

Apply any of this solutions to  `handleSearch,clickHandler,searchFocusHandler` functions